# How can I get rid of a gap between a menu and a submenu

Tags: html, css

So the website I am working on is www.Titusmountain.com. As you can see when you hover over the menu, the submenu appears a good inch below the menu. As you scroll down the site and hover over it, the submenu gets further and further away. Any idea as to what is causing this? I'm not all that great with HTML and CSS.

I've looked through the code and changed a ton of things to no avail.

Comment: i think you should take a good look at the css of the whole page, scrolling messes up the header, but also the cookie alert is all over the place etc.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: I mean I would do this, but as I said I'm not very great with coding so I don't quite no where to look, thus can't post "meaningful code"

Comment: One thing you should focus on learning is browser dev tools. these will tell you exactly what the problem is with an inspector.

Answer (score 0):

The current `.wsite-menu-wrap` class has `top:80px` which is causing the gap between the menu and the submenu.

Changing it to `top:0px` will remove this gap

Comment: I can't find this .wsite-menu-wrap

Comment: you probably can't find it because it is not set with css but with javascript

Answer (score 0):

Remove margin-top from header and change

```
.page-content-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

to

```
.page-content-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Maybe these modifications can break something else, let me know

Comment: This worked for the initial problem, but still when I scroll down the page and then go to the menu the submenu gaps way down the page.